# Why `for x in {1..3}; do echo "$x" && sleep 2 ; done | tee output123` doesn't need `tee -a`?

Tags: bash

command:

`for x in {1..3}; do echo "$x" && sleep 2 ; done | tee output123`
writes

```
1
2
3
```

correctly to `output123`, why `-a` for `tee` is not necessary here?

And I know, for :

`for x in {1..3}; do echo "$x" | tee -a output123 && sleep 2 ; done` ,

it needs `tee -a`.

I guess there's something to do with the bash loop?

Comment: The difference would be visible if you would put something to `output123` before. If you do a `echo test >output123` before the loop, then the _test_ would still be in the file after your script finishes, when you use `tee -a`, but with just `tee`, the _test_ line would be gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first one the loop runs and all its output is given to a single `tee`. In the latter one `tee` is run for each loop iteration so without `-a` each execution of it will just overwrite the file.

Note that these aren’t equivalent if the file already exists.